# Shiny UI: Rendering names for Select Input out of long list of csv files - How to display?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I need to show select input options, which are rendered from a possibly changing list of csv files.

At first step the user decides via radio buttons, which detail view he wants to inspect. Here I just direct to the right folder by adding the path to the selected choice. 
In the second step, the user should be able to select the "fruit" detail view. Therefore, I filtered a huge list of csv files with gsub and this works fine, but the names are not shown in the select input field, furthermore I just get an error message.

To make it more simple, the code:

**ui.R**

```
      tabItem(tabName = "mainTab",

    # control boxes        

    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Please select a fruit representation", 
        width = 12, 
        status = "info",
        color = "maroon",
        collapsible = FALSE,
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "fruit_view", 
          label = "", 
          choices = c("Top Fruit View", 
            "Current Fruit Split",
            "Top Fruit & Value Class"), 
          selected = "Top Fruit View",
          inline = TRUE)
      )
      ),
    fluidRow(

      box(
        title = "Selected Fruit:", 
        width = 4,
        collapsible = FALSE,
        selectInput(
        inputId = "fruit_selection", 
        label = "", 
        choices = "")
```

server.R

```
get_fruitView <- reactive({
  switch(input$fruit_view,
    "Top Fruit View" = dir(
      path = "data/fruits/", full.names = TRUE),
    "Current Fruit Split" = dir(
      path = "data/splits/", full.names = TRUE),
    "Top Fruit & Value Class" = dir
    (path = "data/classes/", full.names = TRUE))
})


# loading the modeled data by fruit

      visible_fruits <- reactive({

      fruit_choiced <- get(input$fruit_view)

      fruit_choice <- view_choiced()[c(gsub(view_choiced(),
        pattern = "[^_]+_[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+", replacement = "\\1"))]

      basename(unique(fruit_choice))
    })

    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "",
        choices = visible_fruits())
    })
```

The regex works fine and isolates the names I want to show, but they get not visible in the user input.

Thanks in advance.

Btw I get this error message:

```
Warning: Error in serverFuncSource: server.R returned an object of unexpected type: environment
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: shiny::runApp
Error in serverFuncSource() : 
  server.R returned an object of unexpected type: environment
Warning: Error in get: object 'input' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    58: get
    57: <reactive:visible_channels> [C:\Users\m.nierhoff\Desktop\AnalyseR\RAnalysen\channel-forecasting/server.R#60]
    46: visible_channels
    45: updateSelectInput
    44: observerFunc [C:\Users\m.nierhoff\Desktop\AnalyseR\RAnalysen\channel-forecasting/server.R#69]
     1: shiny::runApp
```

Comment: I can't verify my comment as I don't have the data, but it looks like you haven't put the `inputId` variable in your `updateSelectInput` so `shiny` doesn't know which `selectInput` to update.

Comment: using ```get``` with ```input$fruit_view``` won't work; And where is ``` view_choiced()``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of dynamically changing your input options. Here I use the `uiOutput` and `renderUI` function pair to create a UI element in my `server.R`, the advantage of this is that `server.R` can execute arbitrary R code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Select CSV demo"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "fruit_view", 
          label = "Select a fruit", 
          choices = c("Top Fruit View"="1", 
                      "Current Fruit Split"="2",
                      "Top Fruit & Value Class"="3"), 
          selected = "1",
          inline = TRUE)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(

         uiOutput("ChoicesUI")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

   output$ChoicesUI <- renderUI({
     a <- read.table(paste0(input$fruit_view,".csv"))
     selectInput("Choices2",
                 label="select from file",
                 choices = a$V1)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have manually created 3 csvs called `1.csv` , `2.csv`, and `3.csv` each with three distinct elements on each row to make this work.

[image]

Let me know if you need further explaining or this doesn't do what you want it to

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @michael-bird . Your example works fine but it seems not working for my problem. I will edit my question to make the problem more visible.